# Get value of control which is generated at run time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have Created a DATALIST at run time and load Webuser control in dalalist itemtemplate. how to get the value of all control under datalist.datalist generated at run time after postback its to be null and recreated again. how to access value?

Answer (score 0):

The DataList has an Items property; you can loop through this, which is the collection of the items bound to the list, and grab the values you need.  To grab the individual controls, use:

```
item.FindControl("ID")
```

To extract them out.

Comment: datalist generated at run time after postback its to be null and recreated again. how to access value.

Comment: You cannot access the original data source, but you can access the controls created from the data source... this shouldn't be a problem, as long as viewstate is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

At `databound` event of `datalist` we get value of any field of `datalist` at runtime.

Comment: a textbox inside a datalist. how to get changed value of textbox after postback. bcoz datalist to be null after postback and recreated.